# Polynomial Fitting with Least Squares using Numpy and Scipy

Tags: optimization, python, regression, least-squares

I am trying to fit data to a polynomial using Python - Numpy. The points, with lines sketched above them are as in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2BkM.png).

I am trying to fit those points to a polynomial of 4. or 5. degree. However, all I can get is nothing more than a line. The coefficients of other than linear terms are too small. I tried to do that both with Numpy and Scipy. In Numpy, I have used the `polyfit` function and followed the example given in [this link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) and in Scipy used the `optimization.curve_fit` function and followed the page in the comment below. (I cannot post more than two links!).

My question is: why do I get a linear fit for such data? I provide high enough data (about 70 points). And how can I improve my fit?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: http://python4mpia.github.io/fitting_data/least-squares-fitting.html

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: From the picture you show, it would appear as if you have quite high $x$ and $y$ values. Consider scaling, i.e. dividing $x$ and $y$ with, say, 1e6, then apply your polynomial fit to those scaled values, and multiply the output points (not the coefficients of the polynomial) with 1e6.

Comment: @OscarB, thanks for your comment. I used the curvefit Toolbox of Matlab and I got similar results. Then I have subtracted the minimum value for both x and y values and then I could get really nice fits both in MATLAB and Python.

Comment: @MaxHutchinson, thanks for your help but I have just solved the issue by subtracting the 'offset' values.

Comment: @OscarB if you like, you can post your comment as an answer to my question. I can then accept it as the answer ;)

Comment: @T-1000 nevermind, its just internet points. But, I would suggest that you divide, rather than subtract, the maximum value. If you have values from 2e6 to 3e6, subtracting the lowest value still means that you have values from 0 to 1e6, a very large interval that can still cause problems. If you divide by the lowest value, the values will range from 1 to 1.5, and the interpolation should behave better. Let me know if it works for you. To unscale, you simply multiply (rather than add) the lowest value on the output.